# Navigation Buttons within Other Subs

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a macro that does the following: My first sheet contains a list of names. Every time I run the macro, a name is added to the list and a new sheet is created. I would now like to, in the same macro, be able to create a button next to each new name every time I add a name that will allow me to navigate to the new sheet since I will be adding many of these. Do you have a suggestion for how I should do this?

Comment: Just add a hyperlink on that name.